# SwiftUI cannot assign dictionary.components to a variable

Tags: ios, swiftui

As the title says, I cannot assign a private variable to dictionary[item].components(). I am not trying to change the value of it, simply trying to copy the value to use it somewhere else. Although, later I may need to know how to change it.

The main errors I encounter are:

1. Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable
2. Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'

My code currently:

```
@Binding var dictionary: [String:Any]
private var passage = ""
let item: String

var body: some View
{
   if let temp = dictionary[item] ?? String // shows main error 1
   {
      passage = temp.components(separatedBy: "|")[0]
   }

   // I also tried the code below instead of what's above, error: Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'components', and the main errors
   // passage = dictionary[item].components(separatedBy: "|")[0]

   let passageArray = passage.components(sepratedBy: " ")
   // there is a bunch more code after this(has nothing to do with issue though)
}
```

Edit: "As you can see, I haven't done much coding in swiftUI ;n:, I'm much more used to oop."

Comment: Read the **basics** of `SwiftUI` again and do some tutorials.
 You cannot have procedural code like
 `passage = temp.components(separatedBy: "|")[0]` in the `body` of the view
 where you have it. This type of code must go into functions or places like `.onAppear`.

Comment: Your code has too many issues. Including syntax errors, invalid scopes, typos.... You need to rethink and rewrite the entire code from the ground up.

Comment: you are using @Binding var dictionary: [String:Any] That means if you want a value out of it in a variable you need to write 

if let temp = dictionary.wrappedValue[item] as? String {

}

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing a lot of concepts from procedural code here.

1 - `Views` are inmutable structs. If you want to change a value type property like `passage`, you should add the @State property wrapper. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state

2 - You cannot make operations inside `body`. It is a computed property that must return a `View`. You can declare variables to use them inside, but to do operation you should use external functions, and call them in `onAppear` methods for example.

Answer (score -1):

Your `body` property shouldn't contain anything except Views. Code like you've written should be moved into a `Button`. In addition, properties that can be modified need to be marked with `@State`. Here is what your code should look like at the end:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let item: String
    @Binding var dictionary: [String: Any]

    @State private var passage = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Press to retrieve passage from the dictionary") {
                passage = dictionary[item] as? String ?? "passage not found"
            }
            
            Text("Your passage: \(passage)")
        }
    }
}
```

Doesn't it look much cleaner?

This is generally how SwiftUI code should be written. Take a look at these [tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-and-combining-views), they'll help you understand how good SwiftUI code should be written. It's pretty easy to get used to so don't worry about it.

Best of luck learning!